# How does the memory allocation (size) works for ZRAM?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, kernel, swap, ram

I have created VM with 2GB RAM, I also create a ZRAM device of disksize 1GB and configured it as a swap device.

```
# sudo modprobe zram num_devices=1
# zramctl --find --size 1024M
# mkswap /dev/zram0
# swapon /dev/zram0
```

So I have 1 GB RAM and 1 GB Swap space (compressed RAM) in my new VM.

Now my question is, what happens when I issue following command?

```
zramctl --find --size 1024M
```

How does it tell kernel that it only has 1GB of total 2GB for normal papge allocation and rest is for ZRAM (RAM block device)? It doesn't allocate 1GB RAM memory for ZRAM block device at this point, correct?

I looked ZRAM kernel driver implementation. When ever it tries to add a page to ZRAM device. It allocates the memory (the 0-order pages) using `alloc_pages(gfp_mask,0)` and link them to create so called `zspage`. 
And use this zspage to store the compressed page.

So this means ZRAM is not allocating 1GB ram during the driver initialization, correct? but allocates dynamically as it needs.

My question is when I spawn a process that need more than 1 GB memory. It should first use all available 1GB and then use ZRAM swap memory. How does the ZRAM tells the kernel that it only can use 1GB and rest of the RAM (1GB) belongs to it?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find info on how zRam actually behaves and functions, but I finally found my answer.

When you initialize a zRam device (/dev/zramX) no ram is actually allocated, and your system will use physical ram as normal until swapping occurs. When this happens, the zRam device starts to use physical memory to store compressed pages, up to a total ammount of uncompressed data equal to the initialized size, which means that the space used by zRam is less than the ammount specified by your command `zramctl --find --size 1024M`.

There are apparently hooks in either `/proc` or `/sys` to query the current state of your zRam disks, but since I just started testing/playing with it this week, I'm not too familiar with it.

Source: [some guy's personal wiki?](http://rdiez.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Linux_zram#How_zram_Swapping_Works)

Answer (score 1):

The OS sees the size of swap disk as specified in ZRAM config, and swaps data less than or equal to that size, it is oblivious of the ZRAM's internal compression. So e.g. if you have 2 GB of RAM and you specifiy 1 GB as ZRAM disk size ->, the OS swaps 1GB of data -> ZRAM compresses that 1GB to 500 MB -> 1.5 GB of RAM is free for other processes to use. The OS 'will think' it has swapped 1GB of data from RAM onto swap disk. That is why you can specify ZRAM disk size greater than the installed RAM and still be able to run other programs completely fine even if ZRAM's disk is full.